# Unable to create connection: Invalid connection details. Please verify you have entered the correct connection details

Tags: mysql, ibm-watson

I am trying to create a connection in IBM Watson Studio but after entering all the right credentials, I still get the error, "Unable to create connection:
Invalid connection details. Please verify you have entered the correct connection details".
I am using mysql db on cpanel.
I wonder what could be causing such behavior.[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwstl.png)

Comment: Have you tried connecting from any other MySQL client, on not on the same server as the MySQL server?

Comment: i tried that. but i still got the same error. i wonder what might be the source of such a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by enabling remote host access on the database server.